# recognize text in html page: how to start

Tags: html

I'd be happy to know how to start if I'd like to create a web sample application that is able, given an email message (i.e. *.html page), to recognize over the body specific words and/or links.

Thank you very much for the collaboration

Giuseppe

Comment: You might want to specify what programming language you are going to use. Also, email is not the same as html page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer at first. You've just striked the problem: i need to understand:
- What is the format of an email
- Which programming code would you suggest to use (i would say Java...)
- anything else

Comment: Give example page, so we can help you. If I understand you need html parser. Nokogiri and Ruby are great for that, although in other languages you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, php is the quickest to learn, and installed on pretty much all hosting providers. You can embed it directly into a web page.

You will need a webserver to run it (or indeed any other language) on.

I would very strongly suggest finding an online tutorial on whatever language you end up choosing, and working through it, so you have some idea of the language, before coming back to this problem.

You will also need to learn the basics of html, if you have not already done so.

Comment: I can say i would do this in Java, even because the right implementation could be, in the future, a servlet or a stand-alone application. Given this, any suggestion about how/where to start? 
Again, thank you